# Python & Pandas: Select data and then set attributes value

Tags: python, pandas

I want to first select data and then set the attribute `artifact` to `True`. I know I can select data by doingt this:

```
df[(df['incre'] > 20)&(df['incre_reverse'] > 20)]
```

However, when I try to set attribute like this:

```
df[(df['incre'] > 20)&(df['incre_reverse'] > 20)].artifact = True
df[df['artifact'] == True]
```

No result is returned.

What's the problem? What's the correct way of assiging values in `Pandas`?

Comment: Is `artifact` already a column or a new column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citing from the documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated):

> Warning Starting in 0.20.0, the .ix indexer is deprecated, in favor of
>   the more strict .iloc and .loc indexers.

So, you should use loc instead as follows:

```
df.loc[(df['incre'] > 20)&(df['incre_reverse'] > 20),'artifact']]=True
```

Answer (score 1):

use ix instead

```
df.ix[(df['incre'] > 20)&(df['incre_reverse'] > 20),'artifact']]=True
```